# Is there any way to integration between Jmeter and Github to push jmx file

Tags: github, jmeter

I am planning to integrate between Jmeter and Github to maintain my file in the private repository,can any one suggest me is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a concept of [Github Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) which allow 3rd-party applications to get 
   information about repository changes
2. The WebHooks can be [secured](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/)
3. JMeter itself doesn't have any integration with any version control system, however you can use i.e. [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) continuous integration server which will "listen" to the Github repository changes and trigger the job which will run a JMeter test when you commit the new version of the test (or whatever action you want to act as the trigger)

See the following articles for more information:

- [How to Integrate Your GitHub Repository to Your Jenkins Project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project)
- [GitHub Permissions and API token Scopes for Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/234710368-GitHub-Permissions-and-API-token-Scopes-for-Jenkins)